# Imagemagick, clear noise from QR-code image

Tags: imagemagick, qr-code, noise-reduction

I have QR-code scanned from document, when I trying do decode it with online decoder, like http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx or other, they not find QR-code, but when I decode with  camera on smartphone, it's decode correct text. I think it's because of small noises in image, how can I clear it with ImageMagick?
[image: Qr-code scanned]

There can be another QR-codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a median filter like this, but you would probably be better off extracting the image from the PDF the way Kurt suggested in your previous question in order to retain more quality:

```
convert qr.png -median 3 result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i think it's working, I will try in other mages too, but think it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the Imagemagick command available, but what you usually do to remove noise is to

- blur the image by 1 or 2 pixels
- lighten it up a bit
- add contrast again

Imagemagick should be able to do all this.